# T-SQL restructure the Sql Statements converting Case into CTE

Tags: t-sql

I have a case statement like -

```
Case FormID  
  When '1025' Then 'QFormName' (These are sub queries)

  When '3026' Then 'DFormName'

  Else 'FormName' End 'FormName'

Case FormID  
  When '1025' Then 'QDFormName' (These are sub queries)

  When '3026' Then 'DDFormName'

  Else 'DFormName' End 'DisplayFormName'
```

I got another statement like this as well.

Is there any way to simplify this SQL using CTE on the top of statement.
Where I can do something like -

```
Case FormID
  When '1026' SET QFormName, SET QDFormName
```

Mean logically i can check formID at one place and find all the three values I want to find.

Thanks,

Comment: flavor of tsql - oracle or sql server?

Comment: @Hogan - so far as I'm aware, only Sybase and MS SQL Server have `tsql`.

Comment: I'm thinking to a table function and join it with cross apply operator. This means you'll move the "sub queries" and the case statements into that function which you might not like this. But is nice to see your full query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want you can do this by declaring a variable and using a batch. (More than one sql statement in a row.)

Any chance you can show the full query or a simplified version that shows the issue -- it is easier to explain if I know exactly what you are doing.